# Cannot find function debugPrint()

Tags: flutter, debugging, dart

In my Flutter project I have besides main.dart a second dart-file (helpers.dart) in which I am trying to use the `debugPrint()` function:

```
debugPrint(someString);
```

I get the following message:

> The function 'debugPrint' isn't defined.
> Try importing the library that defines 'debugPrint', correcting the name to the name of an existing function, or defining a function named 'debugPrint'.

The official Flutter [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/code-debugging#logging) states that the debugPrint function is part of Flutter's foundation library.  But `import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';`  did not solve the problem. So which library/ package do I have to import?

Answer (score 6):

Importing the material package solves the problem:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error:  io_client.dart:57:7: Error: The method 'debugPrint' isn't defined for the class 'IOClient'.

Just go to the related file and comment the line 57 // debugPrint(request.toString());